# How to filter by month and year on updateOrCreate in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

How to filter `created_at` with month and year in Laravel's `updateOrCreate()`?

```
    $statistik = Statistik::updateOrCreate(
        [
            'kode_kantor' => $map->kode_kantor,
            'created_at'  => whereYear('created_at', '=', date('Y-m-d')),
            'created_at'  => whereMonth('created_at', '=', date('Y-m-d'))
        ]
    )->increment('poin_kunjungan');
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for cannot be done by `updateOrCreate()`. You would have to do a manual check. For example:

```
$statistik = Statistik::where('kode_kantor', $map->kode_kantor)
    ->whereYear('created_at', '=', date('Y-m-d'))
    ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', date('Y-m-d'))
    ->first(); 

if(! $statistik) {
    $statistik = Statistik::create([
        'kode_kantor' => $map->kode_kantor
    ]); 
}

$statistik->increment('poin_kunjungan');
```